# Biblatex verbose : change order of fields in entry periodical

Tags: biblatex

I am using the entry "periodical" for a set of articles (with a global editor or not) which is a special issue of a journal. What appears in the footnote is the editor, the journal with some information, a semi-colon and then the issuetitle (that is the title of the special issue). Moreover the page numbers do not appear at all (but if the special issue part is completed with regular items of the journal like reviews or others, it is useful to give the precise page numbers). 
 I would like : Name of the editor if any, ed., Issuetitle, Title of the journal with the number date etc, url or/and page numbers.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[body={110mm, 185mm}, headheight=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[ibidpage=true,autopunct=false, style=verbose-    trad1,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]
 {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
 \let\cite=\smartcite

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@periodical{cat,
editor={Personne, Nemo},
issuetitle= {Actes du Colloque},
title= {Bulletin},
volume={84},
year= {2015},
url={www.sitebulletin.fr},
pages={12-235}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[h][4cm][t]{7cm}
Blabla remplissage\cite{cat}.  Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum     fulgorem surgeret.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and the result
[image: biblatexperiodical]

I would like : Nemo PERSON, ed., *Actes du colloque*, *Bulletin* 84(2015), pages, url.

Comment: Do you want that different order in the bibliography as well? Can you explain about the page numbers?

Comment: I asked only for the citations in footnotes (the bibliography would be a different question, no ?) . The verbose style may have references only in footnotes, with no final bibliography. The page issue is that apparently for the moment the pagenumbers are not printed at all. It may be that "periodical" is not the correct entry (I tried others, but it is the most natural one), but what I have is a special issue of a journal, with a specific issuetitle, which does not occupy the whole journal, thus the pagenumbers. The order question is the most decisive, however. Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe that if I were to change the order in the footnotes it would automatically also change in the bibliography, but if that is fine with you that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to move the `issuetitle` to the front we just need to move the bibmacro `issue` in `standard.bbx`'s `title+issuetitle` bibmacro

```
\renewbibmacro*{title+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{periodical}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \newunit}
```

For the pages field we use the packages [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) to patch the `@periodical` driver to print the `note` and `pages` field instead of only the `note` field. This mirrors the behaviour of `@article`s.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{periodical}
  {\printfield{note}}
  {\usebibmacro{note+pages}}
  {}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[ibidpage=true, autopunct=false, style=verbose-trad1, backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]
 {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
\let\cite=\smartcite

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@periodical{cat,
editor={Personne, Nemo},
issuetitle= {Actes du Colloque},
title= {Bulletin},
volume={84},
year= {2015},
url={http://www.sitebulletin.fr},
pages={12-235}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{title+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{periodical}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{periodical}
  {\printfield{note}}
  {\usebibmacro{note+pages}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
Blabla remplissage\cite{cat}. Tempore quo primis auspiciis in mundanum fulgorem surgeret.
\end{document}
```

[image: relevant footnote 1 of MWE]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! For the record:  I checked that it works perfectly if one has only the url or only the pages (yes, it does). It also works without any editor.